# Python 3.5 - genetic algorithm looping

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import sys
def initial():
    generation = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
    generation = generation
    return generation
def fitness(flag):
    global transfer
    transfer = []
    newgeneration1 = pairing()
    scores = [1,2,3,7,6,5,3]
    if flag < 1:
        generation = initial()
    else:
        generation = newgeneration1
    transfer.append(generation)
    transfer.append(scores)
    print(transfer)
    return transfer
def pairing():
    transfer = fitness(i)
    scores = transfer[1]
    generation1 = transfer[0]
    newgeneration = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]
    return newgeneration

initial()
for i in range(3):
   fitness(i)
   pairing()
   if i == 3:
      scores = fitness(i)
      print("The following is the final generation: ")
      print(pairing(i-1))
      print("Here are the scores: ")
      print(scores)
      sys.exit()
```

Above is a simplified version of what I have in terms of a genetic algorithm code in python 3.5, when I run this I am getting an error that says: maximum recursion depth exceeded, I am trying to get it to do the initial function once, then loop between the fitness and pairing for a certain number of iterations, the problem is, pairing() creates a new generation, and fitness needs to take that new generation and determine its fitness, then it sends that to pairing, and another new generation is created..etc. you get the idea. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `pairing()` called `fitness(i)` and `fitness()` called `pairing()` back without any conditional judgement. It's a dead loop.

Comment: And avoid using `global`.  Instead, pass `transfer` into `paring`

Comment: Don't do `from pylab import *` if you are trying to do reproducible work.  This will clobber your namespace.

Comment: @Sara Kohtz I've answered your question, did it help you? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's the problem:**

So lets walk through your program...

- First you call `initial()`
- Next you call `fitness(i)`
- inside the `fitness` function you call `paring`
- inside the `paring` function you call `fitness`
- inside the `fitness` function you call `paring`....

What you've got here is an infinite loop, because `fitness` and `paring` keep calling each other

**Here's the solution:**

```
def pairing():
    global transfer # transfer is a global variable, you don't need to call a function to get it
    #transfer = fitness(i)
    #scores = transfer[1] # you've already defined these variables, no need to define them again
    #generation1 = transfer[0]
    newgeneration = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]
    return newgeneration
```

I've taken out some unnecessary lines from your paring function, the program now works as it should

**Here's the output:**

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 3]]
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 3]]
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 3]]
```